# How to populate a table while creating the Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a list of cities (simple cvs file) and I want to populate the citeis table while creating the City model.
Class description:

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = modeld.CharField('city_name', max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        berbuse_name =....
        ...........

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city
```

Now, what I am looking for is how to do it only once, while creating the model(DB table).

I'm trying to do it over here because it sound very logic to me (like building a sql script in MS-sql and other)

EDIT: Ok, I guess I am asking the wrong thing....maybe this: How do I create a python function that will take the cvs file and transform it to json (Again, in the model itself, while it is being build) and should I do it at all???

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: csv to JSON is trivial.  Look at the `csv` module and the `json` module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do something like this, usually.

```
import csv
from my_django_app.forms import CityForm
with open( "my file", "rb" ) as source:
    rdr = csv.DictReader( source )
    for row in rdr:
        form= CityForm( **row )
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()
        else:
            print form.errors
```

This validates and loads the data.

After the data is loaded, you can use `django-admin dumpdata` to preserve a JSON fixture from the loaded model.

Comment: Thank you, that is what i needed, althou it is not in the model it self as i understand....but 10x :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Providing initial data for models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/).

Comment: Sorry, but i've read that and can't see how that will help me.... Mabye i'm wrong, but as i said i have a cvs file and i want it to be autoated (lady programmer) not to enter values by hand (that i can do in the admin... Mabye i am missing somthing, but i was think more in the reading the file with python and creating the inserts automatic.... I will Edit my Original question....10x